# Why command from script file isn't found by windows?

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt

I've added drush command to environment variable.
When I go to cmd and run drush command all works ok.

But wheh I'm trying to call drush command inside script file, eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

drush si --site-name=SiteName --account-pass=pass -y
```

an error is raising:

> drush: command not found

Comment: In newest version of GIT for Win all works ok

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you run some alternate shell like `msysgit` on windows. Seems possible that you added this command to msysgit's `$PATH` but the script is executed with the windows builtin `cmd` which is not aware of your alternate shells `$PATH`.

Comment: No, all commands (directly in command prompts or in script file) are executing from windows command line tools (cmd)

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` in a windows (batch)script?

Comment: without it I get same error.